# (discord.py rewrite) How do you disconnect everyone from a discord voice channel?

Tags: discord.py

How would I disconnect everyone from a voice channel in the rewrite of discord.py? I would assume that this would be a `for x in x loop`, but how would I make it so it disconnects each user in the channel? I'm not sure what to add to this. I just basically want to disconnect every user from a certain voice channel if it is not empty.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you have so far?

Comment: I haven't yet tried any code

Comment: Although this might seem like "one feature" this is actually something made up from several different things: getting the voicechannel object, knowing how to kick a person from a voicechannel and iterating through all users. If you haven't tried any code, the best we can do is to just send you the code that does the thing, but it won't help you much except for being a black box where you don't actually know what's happening inside.